# Compare two lists in Excel (without macros?)

Tags: excel, compare, comparison

I have two lists in the same sheet in Excel that I'd like to compare. The cells contain information like "12/345" or "12/3456". What I want to get out the comparison is a list of elements in list A that is not present in list B, and a list of elements in list B that is not present in list A (separated).

Until now I have done it by having list A in column A, and list B in column B. I then sort the columns individually. In column C I have the following formula:

```
=IF(A1=B1;"OK";"ERROR!")
```

When an element is missing in list A, I move the list downwards one step (or more if neccessary). This is a very manual way to do it, so I'd like tips on how to make it more automated. See the attached screenshot for an image that perhaps explains the problem better than words. The lists usually have less than 100 elements each.

[image]

Comment: "a list of elements in list A that is not present in list B" For each cell in list A count if that cell is in list B: `=COUNTIF(B:B,A1); =COUNTIF(B:B,A2); ...; =COUNTIF(B:B,A[n])`. If that is 0 then A[n] is not in list B:B.

Comment: Thank you, Axel! Good thinking :). Consider posting your comment as an answer ...

Answer (score -1):

For the unique values in list1:

1. add a value you know is unique to the end of list1, like "999999"
2. copy list2 below this new value
3. select it all; list1 the 999999 and the copy of list2
4. press "Data/Remove Duplicates" on the ribbon
5. now all the numbers above the 999999 are the unique values of list1
6. Do the corresponding for list2